# Remove repeated item in list in python

Tags: python, list

Let say I have a list of

```
['a','man', 'and', 'a', 'woman']
```

How do I remove the repeated 'a' so that it will only be:

```
['a','man', 'and', 'woman']
```

Comment: I notice you're asking a lot of questions. You should accept the answers in each question that proved helpful.

Comment: Someone asked this and then removed their comment, is order important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order is not important, then you can just do:

```
d = ['a', 'man', 'and', 'a', 'woman']
list(set(d))
```

Comment: May as well leave it as a `set` after doing this

Answer (score 7):

Keeps order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> L = ['a','man', 'and', 'a', 'woman']
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(L))
['a', 'man', 'and', 'woman']
```

Answer (score 1):

If order is important, a suggestion similar to @jamylak's, is to use [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) `OrderedSet` recipe.

```
list(OrderedSet(L))
```

Comment: +1 for `OrderedSet` recipe, however OP will probably not need all the set operations